# Wordpress REST-API + ACF: Can't get featured to show in JSON response

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

Hoping that someone can help me out with this.

I’ve got a custom post type called ‘weeks’ and inside that is repeater fields for post objects which can be added for days of the week. Please see the attached screenshot for reference:

[image: repeater fields]

The JSON response is pumping out the correct information which you can see here:

[image: json response]

I’m wanting to have the featured image in the form of a url of those post_ojbects show in the json output and I think I need to add that field to my functions.php but I’m having no luck. Ideal output something like this:

[image: ideal response]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dayne

Comment: what endpoint did you use? because you may need to create a [custom endpoint](https://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) and from there you can append the the `featured_media` item to json data

Comment: Did you get this figured out by chance?

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://tutel.me/c/wordpress/questions/145283/register.html):

> You can get it without plugins by adding _embed as param to your query

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

Search for "wp API featured image"